# Shall we add a tag if solution involves a particular technology/module?

Tags: discussion, tags, answers

I came upon this question: [how to replace multiple column in one column in txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54016276/how-to-replace-multiple-column-in-one-column-in-txt-file)

The question is only related to Python but most of the solutions involve using a particular module (**panda** in that case).

In these situations where the solutions (or all the best solutions) are related to a particular technology or module, shall we add the tag into the question or leave it unchanged?

*NOTE: during its creation, the question only `python` tag but someone requested adding `panda`)*

Comment: I suspected that it was asked before with about the same answer I provided... Turned out essentially exactly the same "should panda be added to python question" was asked some time ago :) (may by  someone just likes "panda" so much)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov indeed.. opened 3 years ago! But not closed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags should not describe answers, but rather just question.

I believe adding "panda" would be wrong in this case as there very well could be other solutions and it should be somewhat easy to come up with pure Python solution. It is perfectly ok if all answers recommend Panda as it may be *the way* to do it (not a Python expert).